# equivalence relations proof of symmetry

Tags: equivalence-relations

I'm trying to prove $a\sim b \text{ if } a^2-b^2\geq0$. All examples I have been given have not included inequalities. For reflexive we can take $a^2-a^2\geq0$ for $x\in \mathbb{Z}$. What procedure do we use to see if it's symmetric?

Comment: Are you talking about the relation $R$ given by $aRb\iff a^2-b^2 \geq 0$? Then for symmetry, try out a few examples. Do we have $1R2$? Do we have $2R1$? See what happens, and then write a proof based on that.

Comment: Is this the original task? This is not true. Take a=0 and b=1, then $0-1=-1<0$